# Cron generated by ISPConfig

Tags: cron

I have a problem with crontab generated by ISPConfig.

```
MAILTO=''
*    *    *    *    *    web9    /usr/bin/wget -q -O /dev/null 'http://inz.isedo.pl/test/cron.php' >/dev/null 2>&1    #inz.isedo.pl
```

In log, I have a errors:

```
Feb 16 21:11:01 s /usr/sbin/cron[21697]: (*system*ispc_web9) RELOAD (/etc/cron.d/ispc_web9)
Feb 16 21:11:01 s /USR/SBIN/CRON[23817]: (web9) CMD (/usr/bin/wget -q -O /dev/null 'http://inz.isedo.pl/test/cron.php' >/dev/null 2>&1^I#inz.isedo.pl)
Feb 16 21:11:01 s /USR/SBIN/CRON[23816]: (CRON) error (grandchild #23817 failed with exit status 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

- Does it work from the command line ?
- Can you redirect the stdout and stderr to a file (as opposed to null) and pass on the output ?

Comment: 1. When I put in command line: /usr/bin/wget -q -O /dev/null 'http://inz.isedo.pl/test/cron.php' >/dev/null 2>&1    #inz.isedo.pl is ok and working. 2. I dont know, I do not know how to check.

Comment: /usr/bin/wget -q -O /dev/null 'inz.isedo.pl/test/cron.php'; > /tmp/isedo_cronlog 2>&1